# Applying a Gradient to a Circle in FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Is it possible to wrap a (for instance) Circle in a LinearGradient or visa versa in FXML only?

I imagine something like this:

```
<BorderPane prefWidth="800" prefHeight="600" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
...
    <center>
        <Circle fx:id="circle" centerX="400" centerY="300" stroke="#9922ff" radius="150">
            <LinearGradient ...>

            </LinearGradient>
        </Circle>
    </center>
...
</BorderPane>
```

The gradient should apply only to the circle and nothing else. I would like to show that example in a presentation.

**EDIT:**
James gave me a good hint, but what I actually need is the takeover of the following code:

```
private Circle createCircle() {
    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0f, 1f, 1f, 0f, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
            new Stop(0, Color.web("#ffffff")),
            new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#9922ff")),
            new Stop(1, Color.web("#ffffff")));

    Circle circle = new Circle(150, gradient);
    circle.centerXProperty().set(400);
    circle.centerYProperty().set(300);
    circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
    circle.setStroke(Color.web("#9922ff", 0.5));
    circle.setStrokeWidth(20);

    return circle;
}
```

I also have an animation for this circle, but this is nothing for FXML, that's clear for me. :) Does someone know how to fully use the gradient int FXML?

Comment: IMO, you are better off defining gradients in CSS rather than FXML.  FXML is better for layout, CSS is better for style.

Comment: You think you can apply a gradient in CSS? This topic becomes more and more interesting. :)

Comment: Yes, see [the JavaFX CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FXML equivalent of the Java code you posted is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <Circle fx:id="circle" centerX="400" centerY="300" stroke="#9922ff"
            radius="150">
            <fill>
                <LinearGradient startX="0.0" startY="1.0" endX="1.0"
                    endY="0.0" proportional="true" cycleMethod="NO_CYCLE">
                    <stops>
                        <Stop offset="0">
                            <color>
                                <Color red="1.0" green="1.0" blue="1.0" />
                            </color>
                        </Stop>
                        <Stop offset="0.5">
                            <color>
                                <Color red="0.6" green="0.133" blue="1.0" />
                            </color>
                        </Stop>
                        <Stop offset="1.0">
                            <color>
                                <Color red="1.0" green="1.0" blue="1.0" />
                            </color>
                        </Stop>
                    </stops>
                </LinearGradient>
            </fill>
        </Circle>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

though I agree with the comments after the question, that this is probably better done in CSS.

Comment: Yeah, Indeed it does! But I'm not able to put in all my wanted attributes. I edited my question with the content. I can set start and end coordinates, but I don't find a way to insert stops and colors. Thanks for your help james. :)

Comment: Amazing. Where can I learn this? I don't understand how you were aware that you, for instance, need to put a "stops" tag and put all the stops between it. Is there some logic you can apply or is this just your experience? How did you know you can write a "<stops>" here?

Comment: See the documentation. `LinearGradient` defines a [`getStops()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html#getStops--) method (and no `setStops()` method), so it's a "Read only list property" as defined in the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements).

Comment: I should mention that not everything is documented: for example this only works because the parameters to the `LinearGradient` constructor are annotated `@NamedArg`, and this isn't documented. So for some parameters I just had to hope it was set up in an intuitive way.